# imap `^^` to `^{}<++>` and place cursor inside

Tags: key-bindings

I want to `imap` the sequence `^^` to `^{}<++>` and then place the cursor inside the brackets. (This is handy when editing *Latex* code and is a nice feature of the *vim latex suite* which I have recently abandoned)

The straight forward approach doesn't work for me:

`:imap ^^ ^{x}<++><esc>Fxs`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inoremap ^^ ^{}<++><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

Is ugly, but it should work.

See `:h i_<Left>`

Comment: Thanks, it does. But not in GVIM for some reasons. Have you tried it there?

Comment: Works in gVim for me. Have you re-mapped `<Left>`? Try `:imap <Left>`.

Comment: I don't get it to work in gvim. Even so when I start it blank via `gvim -u NONE`.

Comment: How about if you `:set nocompatible` and then bind it? That seemed to work for me.

Comment: @Jan You should probably use `inoremap` instead of `imap`. Not sure if that fixes it, but it might.

Comment: Thanks, but neither of your suggestions helps. :( I also tried it on a different computer.

Comment: I mark this as answering the question. Although I seem to have conflicts with my plugins.

Answer (score 1):

With [lh-bracket](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets)s (which proposes similar features, and which is compatible with latex-suite when installed -- latex-suite installs a plugin named imaps.vim that has side effects with mappings (*)), It would be:

```
:Brackets ^{ } -trigger=^^ -visual=0
```

The placeholder will be added as well, and the result will be compatible with vim 7.4-*patchnumberIdontremember* redo feature.

(*) If you are still able to use placeholders (as I see you'll like to have `<++>` after the closing bracket), and if you are not using lh-brackets, it's likely you have imap.vim still active. This may explain why the mappings proposed in the other answers don't work in your case. Another possible explanation is that `^` is a dead key on some keyboard. Half the time it's the case on my French systems.

Comment: thanks for this -- well analysed. I have `imaps.vim` installed. I thought that `gvim -u None` will not load plugins but it actually does. I will try your solution in a second.

Comment: when finally executing the map `^^`, I end up with this error message: ```Error detected while processing function lh#brackets#opener[71]..lh#map#insert_s
eq:
line    4:
E117: Unknown function: lh#dev#reinterpret_escaped_char```

Comment: lh-brackets has a few dependencies. Don't forget to install them. At least lh-vim-lib and lh-dev are required.